# How to create a custom progressDialog with percentage and message instead of deprecated ProgressDialog

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I created a custom progress dialog using progressbar, but the progress message in the custom progressdialog is not updating

Comment: add some codes of what you have done so far please

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar) to achieve the same behavior as 
ProgressDialog

```
CustomProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressbar);
progressBar.setMax(100);
progressBar.setProgress(1);
```

You can call the `setProgress()` method inside your Async call/Any Listener's `onProgressChange()` method with the next `progress` value

- To add a text message along with the ProgressBar

I'd suggest writing a custom Class that extends ProgressBar since this cannot be done directly - in this custom class, You should override `onDraw()` inside `ProgressBar`, and use `Canvas.drawText()` to decide where the text should be positioned. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) you can find the documentation for `drawText()` - `x and y are the coordinates of the origin of the text is drawn`

--
You can also checkout this blog on [Display Percentage on ProgressBar](http://suyu-android-dev.blogspot.com/2012/09/display-percentage-on-progressbar.html)

Hope this helps, let me know if you are looking for something else.